# Ubuntu 20.04 Windows Printer via SAMBA browse click no response

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I have tried to use several guides and search askubuntu, but have not found a way to solve the following problem.

I have a shared printer setup up on Windows 10. On my Ubuntu 20.04 I go to Settings-Printers-Additional Printer Settings...-add-Network Printer-Windows Printer via SAMBA. In the SMB Printer I click Browse... but nothing happens. From the tutorials I have looked at a window should pop up, but that doesn't happen. I don't know how to find the smb://[workgroup]... string for the printer so I haven't tried to use that.

Is my SAMBA installed correctly? or is it another problem?

I hope you can help me. As I am quite new to Linux, please explain how to fix it clearly.

Comment: Apparently SAMBA is not installed on my system. I will try that first and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: The problem is the same after installing SAMBA.

Comment: I think you try good method. Have you python3-smbc installed? (to check: dpkg -l |grep python3-smbc) Did you check firewall? try to allow samba (sudo ufw allow samba).

Comment: Thank you Xzu for a good answer. I am not at work right now so I can say for sure if it works. But now something happens if I click the button, so definitely going the right way.

Comment: Yes, but we are not yet out of the woods. Personally, systemconfigPrinter ask me for non-existent password to access workgroup on 20.04.  Let me know for you.

Comment: Got a step further now. It says No Print Shares - There were no no print shares found. Please check that the Samba service is marked as trusted in your firewall configuration.

I already did the (sudo ufw allow samba)

Comment: Made it a step further, I had to add the IP address in the box. (I guess that computer will change IP address every time it starts - how can I get around that?). So now I am at the same problem I am asked to login and give username, workgroup and password. The computer with the printer doesn't have a password, so what do I do here?

Comment: I have tried to make a user on the Windows computer (just for printer), but it still doesn't work. I have tried to search for guides on the problem, but no-one seems to have this problem (prompted for a password when no password is set)

Comment: Please join me here( and send me MP) https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2450155 .AskUbuntu is not adapted for our investigation.

Comment: Please signal you are concerned by clicking on the green sentence in the top of the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1895852

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt install python3-smbc smbclient
```

The above command works for me.